# How to troubleshoot internal DNS resolution (Windows DNS server) pointing to a local server with a static internal IP address

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, internal-dns, domain-name, troubleshooting

To better explain the set up

- I have a Debian server in a private network with a static IP.
- There is a windows AD server that resolves DNS for clients internally.
- A domain name is already registered and a public IP is pointed to the
  server
- AAA record mapping to the static IP internally has been done (as i have
  been told)

Basically when you type in the domain name it does not reach the debian sever.

I dont have access to anything in the private network except the debian server.

How do i troubleshoot this issue? this web server was working before so it is not the firewall.

I can provide any required files from the debian server, please help out or even a helpful link would be fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To troubleshoot DNS, there are a couple of things to understand.

1. What DNS server your Debian server is using. Can be found in /etc/resolv.conf
2. What domain you are trying to find a server in. Typically the domain is the last part of the web address.
3. What DNS is authoritative for the domain

From what it sounds like, you could be facing split-brain DNS. The public registrar as well as the Windows AD server are authoritative for the same domain.

If you are facing split-brain, you will have to create the AAA records on the Windows AD DNS server to support internal clients.

If the IP address matches what you expect, then you will have to investigate the network routing or possibly firewalls that might be in place.

Comment: Sorry for the late response and thank you for your answer, I did not know it was called split DNS and this led me to properly troubleshoot my problem.